# Include list_route methods in Django REST framework's API root

Tags: python, django, rest, url-routing

I'm using the Django REST framework, and I have a view set with an extra list route method. How can I get that method's URL included in the API root page?

Here's a simplified version of my view set:

```
class BookViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = Book.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BookSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, )

    @list_route(methods=['get'])
    def featured(self, request):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset()).filter(featured=True)

        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

I register the view set in `urls.py`:

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('books', BookViewSet)
urlpatterns = patterns(
    url(r'^api/', include(router.urls), name='api_home'),
    #...
    )
```

The URL for `books/featured` is routed properly, but when I go to `http://localhost:8000/api`, I only see this:

```
HTTP 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS

{
    "books": "http://localhost:8000/api/books/"
}
```

How can I get an entry added for something like this?

```
"book-featured-list": "http://localhost:8000/api/books/featured"
```

Comment: It looks like the way to do this is with a [custom router](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#custom-routers), and maybe override the `get_api_root_view()` method of [`DefaultRouter`](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/4e5da16961c8f11d01a2f9dc475efacb29e778c7/rest_framework/routers.py#L273).

Comment: Note: `list_route` has been [deprecated and removed](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/community/3.8-announcement/#deprecations), and is replaced with `@action(detail=False)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to inherit from DefaultRouter which is responsible for api root view and redefine get_api_root_view method.

```
class MyRouter(routers.DefaultRouter):
    def get_api_root_view(self):
        """
        Return a view to use as the API root.
        """
        api_root_dict = OrderedDict()
        list_name = self.routes[0].name
        for prefix, viewset, basename in self.registry:
            api_root_dict[prefix] = list_name.format(basename=basename)

        class APIRoot(views.APIView):
            _ignore_model_permissions = True

            def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
                ret = OrderedDict()
                namespace = request.resolver_match.namespace
                for key, url_name in api_root_dict.items():
                    if namespace:
                        url_name = namespace + ':' + url_name
                    try:
                        ret[key] = reverse(
                            url_name,
                            args=args,
                            kwargs=kwargs,
                            request=request,
                            format=kwargs.get('format', None)
                        )
                    except NoReverseMatch:
                        # Don't bail out if eg. no list routes exist, only detail routes.
                        continue

                ret['book-featured-list'] = '%s%s' % (ret['books'], 'featured/')

                return Response(ret)

        return APIRoot.as_view()
```

P.S. sorry, didn't see your comment before I posted the answer

Comment: My comment was just a vague suggestion, thanks for fleshing it out.

Comment: Actually, I was hoping to use the `@list_route` decorator to discover all the custom routes instead of having to list them explicitly. I'll look at `SimpleRouter` to see if I can figure out how to add that.

Answer (score 2):

You can install package django-rest-swagger, just follow here: https://github.com/marcgibbons/django-rest-swagger

It is more powerful than DRF's api list page. It will list all the rest apis (include list_route/detail_route apis) for your modules, and you can also do some api test (CRUD) on the page.

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

I use this solution based on likeon's answer:

```
class MyRouter(routers.DefaultRouter):
    def get_api_root_view(self, api_urls=None):
        api_root_dict = OrderedDict()
        list_name = self.routes[0].name
        for prefix, viewset, basename in self.registry:
            api_root_dict[prefix] = list_name.format(basename=basename)

        api_root_dict['books/featured'] = 'book-featured'

        return self.APIRootView.as_view(api_root_dict=api_root_dict)
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you try with, put this below your urlpatterns.
Your url will be like this:

```
http://localhost:8000/api/books/

from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns

urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/format-suffixes/) says that `format_suffix_patterns` lets you use a suffix to specify the response format instead of using HTTP headers. For example, I could ask for `/api/books.json` or `/api/books.html`. I also tried it, and saw no new entries in the `/api` page.